# SwiftUI - making a variable the same kind of the other one

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list populated by core data, in SwiftUI and I am trying to make that list filtered.

So I have this core data entity class...

```
@objc(Expression)
public class Expression: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {

}

extension Expression {
    
  @NSManaged public var term: String?
  @NSManaged public var description: String?
  @NSManaged public var excerpt: String?
 
   
  static func getAllItemsRequest() -> NSFetchRequest< Expression > {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Expression> = Expression.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Expressao>
    request.returnsDistinctResults = true
    
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "term", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return request
  }
```

and I have this List view:

```
struct FilteredList: View {
  
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var coreDataContext

  @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Expression.getAllItemsRequest())
  private var allItems: FetchedResults<Expression>
```

Now I want to create a computed var that filters `allItems`...

If `allItems` was a regular array of `Expression`, I would do this

```
var filteredItems:[Expression] {
    allItems.filter {(item) -> Bool in
      searchText.isEmpty ? true : matchSearch(expression:item)
    }
}
```

but because `filteredItems` must be of the same type of `allItems`, I suppose I have to write it as

```
var filteredItems:FetchedResults<Expression> {
    allItems.filter {(item) -> Bool in
      searchText.isEmpty ? true : matchSearch(expression:item)
    }
}
```

If I do so, I get an error on the filter line:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[FetchedResults<Expression>.Element]' (aka 'Array<Expression>') to return type 'FetchedResults<Expression>'
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Cannot convert return expression of type
> '[FetchedResults<Expression>.Element]' (aka 'Array<Expression>') to
> return type 'FetchedResults<Expression>'
> ```

This error shows you that your `filteredItems` function already returns an array of elements of type `Expression` (but you try to enforce a non-matching return type):

```
var filteredItems:FetchedResults<Expression> {
    allItems.filter {(item) -> Bool in
      searchText.isEmpty ? true : matchSearch(expression:item)
    }
}
```

So why do you want it to be of type `FetchedResults<Expression>`?

If you plan to use this computed property in your view (e.g., in some `ForEach`) you can just change the return type to `[Expression]`:

```
var filteredItems: [Expression] {
    allItems.filter { item in
      searchText.isEmpty ? true : matchSearch(expression: item)
    }
}
```

This way you will return the correct type which can also be used directly in your View.

Comment: I am new to Swift and I am just using SwiftUI for a couple of weeks, trying to get my head around it. It is becoming easier to understand but somethings are insane. The worst part is that, as always, Apple does not give a crap. No documentation at all and we have to learn by ourselves from the web and Stack Overflow. Thanks. I will be returning to Stack Overflow soon with more questions... . thanks